# Can't download apps from Google Play store via mobile network

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, mobile-network, sony-xperia-sola

I have a **Sony Xperia sola** in Egypt. I bought it with Gingerbread, then I upgraded to ICS 4.0.4. After the upgrade, I became unable to download any apps from Google Play using my mobile network, and while using Wi-Fi the download is slower than before the upgrade.

I tried all available solutions like clearing cache or clearing data from Google Play or Google Services Framework, in *Settings* -> *Apps* -> *All*. How can I fix this problem? As it is very serious, many times I'm at places without Wi-fi and I need to download a missing app, or upgrade another one.

Comment: Have you checked your APN settings are correct? Have you set it to 'GSM/WCDMA preferred' by default?

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds stupid, but when the time and date are wrong, most Google apps won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with data connectivity. You can check this (See, for example, [here](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-nexus/462821-need-help-understanding-connectivity-icons.html))) by either

- Looking the type of your data connectivity in

  settings -> about phone -> status -> mobile network type
- Consulting the icon indicator on top. H+ and 3G should allow you to download apps.

It you are not on a fast network it may be that the APN settings are not correct for your carrier or that your account is not defined correctly with your carrier. For APN settings you can consult your carrier, its web site or an app (look for APN and your country name). For account definition you'll need to consult your carrier.

WiFi maybe slower because 4.0 is heavy on the Xperia sola because it only has 512MB RAM. You can watch the RAM load with an app such as [Android system info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Mobile Data plan or working WiFi connection:

1. Go to App Info page of Play store.
2. `Clear data` and then `Clear cache`
3. Then click on `Force stop`
4. Now download latest Play store .apk file from [this link](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/)
5. After the download, install the Play Store from the file.
6. Done.

Answer (score -3):

If nothing works just go to Google hangout installed on your devica and sign in and signout 5 times,then return to playstore and try downloading any app,it might work. I called up the google support team and got the issue fixed in this way.